# Random Kubuntu freeze up

Tags: nvidia, xorg, kubuntu, freeze, kde

I'm kinda new at Ubuntu/Kubuntu, and I had a few issues. For whatever reason, and at random times Kubuntu locks up and I cannot use either mouse nor keyboard. I have tried jumping to terminal mode, but even that doesn't work. Actually, while I was typing this, it crashed and I had to switch to my Eee Pad. I've searched Google, ran diagnostics, and tried to read system logs, with little luck. I think the problem may lie in my graphics, but I'm willing to do anything to fix it.

If it helps at all, when I ran the diagnostics my PC failed the "graphics/display" category.

Comment: Are you using Cairodock or GLDock at all? I found that this would cause my KDE desktop to lockup periodically.

Comment: No, I'm not using either of those

Comment: More information on the harware will score you extra points and better answers, include models, series, extra hardware that you might use, etc.

Comment: also, could you give details of what video drivers you are using?

Comment: I am using a Dell Inspiron 8200, Nvidia geforce2 go(nvidia-96xx), Intel pentium  4m 1.6ghz(1 core 1 thread), 768mb ram, 30gb Hitachi Travel star hdd, Crystal wdm audio, 3com integrated Ethernet, Intel pro wireless 2200bg(ipw2200)

Comment: If it's any consolation, I'm seeing the same thing on my system as well, on both Unity and Xfce, and I just had new nvidia 280M cards put in. At least you know you aren't alone.

Comment: So it's something with NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: I have the same problem with my asus 1201n laptop, NVIDIA driver as well :). But I run Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit. I run the classic desktop.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

If you computer hardware diagnostics is failing on the graphics card as you say it is not related to software, Ubuntu or drivers, your hardware is defect.

Knowing this it is normal that you might have crashes like that: your computer hangs because something really bad happened due to the hardware fault.

You should take your computer to a repair shop or if you can do it yourself and its possible you should replace the defect hardware.

- If you are using an external graphics you should test it with a
  different card (same chipset if possible so you dont need to install
  / remove drivers), reason for that is that it can be just the card
  but your motherboard can be the cause instead.
- If you are using an internal graphics card (built-in) you should try
  to replace the RAM you have (since the card uses shared memory with
  RAM) and if that did not help your motherboard needs to be replaced.